# How to use Latexdiff with TexLive

Tags: latexdiff

I am trying to use `latexdiff` to compare two tex documents on my pc. I use `TexLive` to compile my latex documents. I know the `latexdiff` package is already installed with under `C:\texlive\2016\bin\win32` folder, but I do not know how to use it. My questions are:

1. how to use `latexdiff`? do I click `latexdiff` then the Terminal shows up? then do I write the command there `latexdiff old.tex new.tex > diff.tex`? I have tried this, but I could not write anything in the Terminal (a terminal appears but just for less than 1 second).
2. if I want to compare two tex files, where or under what path should I put these two tex files?
3. do I run latexdiff script in `TexLive` with macros or applyscript?

I hope someone can help me, please!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you read the manual?

Comment: Yes I do. I installed pearl script and I tried to run latexdiff (since pearl), but i don´t know why i can´t write in the terminal.

Comment: with `texmaker` panel "source viewer" can help to find differences between two files

Comment: The terminal probably opens and closes because the command is run without arguments, which is not a valid mode, so it closes with an error message (which you can't see because the window closes even before there was enough time to print the message).

Comment: You need to open the terminal first (in Windows 7 and maybe other version, too, type cmd in search box, or find "command line prompt" or similar in Accesoires in Menu). Then run latexdiff from there (you might need to be some basic Windows command line basics).

Answer (score 0):

1. Run "Windows PowerShell".
2. Run the command `latexdiff old.tex new.tex > diff.tex` in the PowerShell.
3. Compile diff.tex with TexLive or TexStudio.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a new folder and copy a old tex file and a new tex file into it.

1. Ensure your Texlive was installed rightly
2. Press windows+r on your keyboard
3. Input `cmd` and press the Enter key
4. Input `latexdiff` and press Enter key

if it shows as follow:

```
2 and only 2 non-option arguments required.  Write latexdiff -h to get help
```

that means you can use latexdiff in your computer. Otherwise, you may need to install Perl.

5. Input `drive letter+:` and press the Enter key to enter the drive where the tex files exist.

for example:

```
e:
```

6. Input `cd + folder name` and press the Enter key to enter the folder where the tex files exist.

for example:

```
cd difffolder
```

7. Input `latexdiff + space + old file name + space + new file name + space + > + space + diff.tex` and press the Enter key

for exapmle:

```
latexdiff old.tex new.tex > diff.tex
```

8. Then there will create a diff.tex file in the folder automatically. Run diff.tex, and you will get a compared pdf file.

Ps: if it appears errors, try the following code:

```
latexdiff origin.tex modify.tex > diff.tex --encoding=ascii
```